# how to add User roles like buyer seller admin and show homepage based on his roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I need a code that help me

1. Signup/Signin
2. Send welcome email, account confirmation email
3. Implement forgot password
4. User Roles Customer, Seller Show homepage based on role
5. Cancel account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For authentication(Signup/Signin, send welcome email, account confirmation email, forgot password, cancel account) you can take a look at [devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise) and for authorization(User roles) you can take a look at [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan).